# difference between STRONG typing and STATIC typing

Tags: strong-typing, static-typing

I know the difference between static and dynamic typing, and i know the difference between strong and weak typing, but i was asked a question about the difference between **STRONG** and **STATIC** typing!

but as I know strong and static typing talk about different topics from the first place!
so I dont know how to answer this question, anyone knows what they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Static** typed programming languages are those in which variables need not be defined before they’re used. 
Programming languages in which variables have specific data types are **strong** typed
 variables are necessarily bound to a particular data type in strong typed

source :http://www.sitepoint.com/typing-versus-dynamic-typing/
hope it helps

Comment: what do you think "variables need not be defined before they're used" means?
does it mean that in a statically typed language this code will run without errors:
 int num;
 int x=num+1;
?

Comment: That's a really bad answer.